# How to change uploaded image from text/x-genric to image/x-genric

Tags: java, php, android, image, okhttp

I have successfully uploaded an image from my android application to a server folder using php web service but the image is stored in a text/x-genric Type instead of image/x-genric. I uploaded the image from my app to the server using OkhttpClient. Also the stored image at the server doesn't bear its original image name. Please guys how can i fix these two issues. My upload code is shown below, thanks.

upload code:

```
public class HttpUploader2 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

private static final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE = MediaType.parse("image/*");

private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();



public HttpUploader2(){

}

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(String... imgPath) {

    Response response = null;

    for (String path: imgPath){

        RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBuilder()
                .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("name", "Profile Pic")
                .addFormDataPart("filename", "name", RequestBody
                        .create(MEDIA_TYPE, new File(path)))
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(Const.IMAGE_UPLOAD_URL)
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();

        try {
            response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            Log.e("Path: ", path);
            Log.e("Body: ", ""+response.body().string());
            Log.e("Code: ", ""+response.code());

            if (!response.isSuccessful()){
                return response.code();
            }else {
                return response.code();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

    return response.code();
}
```

Comment: "image is stored in a text/x-genric" -- this does not make too much sense. The image is stored on a file system on the server, it has no stored mime type. The server, however, may serve the saved file as text/x-genric. So you need to fix your server mime config to identify the mime type correctly, or maybe fix the php code to save the file extension correctly.

Comment: i tried uploading from an html form and it saved with the correct type at the server

Comment: What do you mean by "saved with the correct type at the server"? You mean the server would serve the file with the correct mime type? Was the file name different on the server? Were the file's contents different on the server?

Comment: yes the server, serves the file with the correct mime type......also the file name wasn't different after i uploaded the image.

Comment: @P.Péter, what do you think...might be the problem?

Comment: I cannot say anything until you provide me with specific answers for my previous questions.

Comment: I finally solved it.... i was supposed to add .jpg to the name value of the image at this line of code                 .addFormDataPart("filename", "name.jpg", RequestBody

Comment: You could add that as an answer, maybe someone will find it useful later. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not standard of image/x-generic type. Frequent used types are [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type). So use image/jpg probably.

```
private static final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE = MediaType.parse("image/jpg");
```

Also probably main issue is in server handling of this request (maybe for unexpected image type).

Answer (score 0):

Add .jpg to the name value in this line of code

```
.addFormDataPart("filename", "name.jpg", RequestBody
```

Answer (score 0):

rename the file name with the same format of the file and save, like if it is image.PNG then rename it to image.png and it will work for sure.